# Copying a string char by char in another string

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have a string type and I am trying to copy this into another string type char by char but when I try to display the output of new copied it is coming as blank. Where as when I try to output char by char for that copied string length its alright. Please see this small code and output for better understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name = "Tom";
    string temp;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < name.length(); ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = name[i];
    }
    cout<<name<<endl;     //gives the output Tom
    cout<<temp<<endl;     //gives blank
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<temp[i];    //gives output char by char
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Tom

Tom
```

I know there are other possible ways to achieve what I am trying to do but just out of thought tried this and it didn't work. So looking for some explanation.

Comment: `temp` has zero length, so you cannot use indexing to address any of its characters.  Use `temp.push_back(name[i]);` to make `temp` grow.

Comment: [Usiing at()  shows your code will not work due to you going out of bounds of the string](http://rextester.com/HER88905)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `temp` is empty, its length is `0`. Then `temp[i] = name[i];` leads to [undifined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); anything is possible but nothing is guaranteed.

You can give it an initial length like:

```
string name = "Tom";
string temp(name.length(), '\0');
```

Comment: I get that, still not clear as why in for loop it was giving right answer.

Comment: @rakeshsinha [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means anything is possible; but nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate data for the temp string to change any data in it.

```
string temp(name.length(),'\0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(; i < name.length(); ++i) temp.push_back(name[i]);
```

Don't assign.